# Getting error when using Google Map Api. Google Api key is not authorized to use this api

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem when using Google Maps Api Key with a Search box. The maps can show but when i type some words into search box, nothing happened.

This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .controls {
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 32px;
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        #pac-input {
            background-color: #fff;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 300;
            margin-left: 12px;
            padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            width: 300px;
        }

            #pac-input:focus {
                border-color: #4d90fe;
            }

        .pac-container {
            font-family: Roboto;
        }

        #type-selector {
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #4d90fe;
            padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
        }

            #type-selector label {
                font-family: Roboto;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 300;
            }

        #target {
            width: 345px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

    function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBoHGi6ROnyyKd1AsQA-ShDMMBUcXeruIk&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is Error
[image]

And this keys:

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank in advanced

Comment: Have you enabled the Google Maps Javascript API v3 for that key? What is the warning indicated next to your key (the yellow triangle with the exclamation point in it)?

Comment: @ geocodezip: this warning require a domain , but i think it is not the problem. i tried to set LocaHost domain for it, but it does not work.

Comment: It's not working. You are getting a warning. I would think that would indicate a problem. The only other thing would be if you haven't enabled the Google Maps JavaScript API for that key/project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the API key is set up to allow access from localhost.

Try changing the following in your address bar from:

```
http://localhost:49812/HtmlPage1.html
```

to

```
http://127.0.0.1:49812/HtmlPage1.html
```

If that doesn't work go to the google console, click the server key you are using and in "Accept requests from these server IP addresses" make sure 127.0.0.1 is in the list.

Comment: @ David: I didn't setup any domain, i want it can run anywhere

Comment: You will need to specify the domain as far as I am aware.

Comment: i tried to set http://localhost:49812 for domain, but it does not work, and i am use Browser key.

Comment: Have you used the 127.0.0.1 address to access your script.

Comment: @ David: i don't know how to change to 127.0.0.1, An error "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
" when i tried to change to 127.0.0.1 in Properties of Project, i am working with Asp.net project.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure these APIs are enabled
[image]